# Django Logging i18n ugettext_lazy Variables

Tags: django, logging, internationalization

I'm having trouble logging the output of an internationalized django variable.

My application code used the 'message' vaiable OK and it displays
in English and German (the two languages I am working with)

My problem is when I try to make a log of the said 'message' variable output.
I want to log in English and/or German (depending on what the end user is seeing)

I'm using string_concat and it says:

the lazy translations in result will only be converted to strings when result 
itself is used in a string (usually at template rendering time).

Here is a code sample:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils.translation import string_concat

message = _('Profile Updated OK')

# Build a log message
fmt_msg = _(message)
log_message = 'Message Sent: '
log_message = string_concat(log_message, fmt_msg)

logger.info(log_message)
```

The log entry is not translated:

```
Message Sent: <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x9c3c4ac>
```

Can anyone suggest how I can have the proxy object to be translated
when used with logging?

It's translating OK in my regular Django code just the logging.info() issue.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#lazy-translation):

> The result of a `ugettext_lazy()` call can be used wherever you would use a unicode string (an object with type `unicode`) in Python. If you try to use it where a bytestring (a `str` object) is expected, things will not work as expected, since a `ugettext_lazy()` object doesn't know how to convert itself to a bytestring.

Also, don't call `_()` twice.

```
logger.info(u'Message Sent: %s' % message)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to force Unicode strings, as documented in http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter19/

`u"Hello %s" % ugettext_lazy("people")`

And do not call the function twice ;)

Comment: 'Message Sent:' does not need translating. string_concat will join a regular string to a lazy translation object.

Comment: Hrm .. I just restarted my django dev server and the code I've posted seems to work fine. Not sure what I was doing wrong but it's OK now. Apologies for wasting time. Thanks!

Comment: Ows ... no sorry .. it's not working. (sorry late Sunday night here). It does translate OK in code rendered to HTML just not the logging.